# Need To Repeat My Animtae Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to make some clouds effect and loop this effect , i need to make some divs and move them from left to right like my code . but my problem that i cant Repeat the function :( any help

`var windowWidth = $(window).width();`

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#cloud").animate({
                          left: "-50"
                          },9000, "linear", function () {
                       $("#cloud").delay(50).animate({
                                   left: windowWidth },9000,"linear");
                          });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery .animate() accepts a callback function which will fire when the animation is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cloud = $('#cloud'),
        animateCloud = function() {
            var direction = $cloud.css('left').slice(0,1) === '-' ? '0px' : '-50px' 
            $cloud.animate({left: direction}, 9000, "linear", animateCloud);
        };
    animateCloud();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XVzk4/

Comment: its not working , Can u make it simple to understand it im just in the start level man :(

Comment: @MohamedSamy posted a working jsfiddle so you can see whats going on. Basically I've created a function which animates the cloud left and right. When the animation completes it call itself. Note you need to call `animateCloud();` to actually start the animation.